# Speeding up this tfidf vectorizer

Tags: python, performance

After thoroughly profiling my program, I have been able to pinpoint that it is being slowed down by the vectorizer.

I am working on text data, and two lines of simple tfidf unigram vectorization is taking up 99.2% of the total time the code takes to execute. I am extending the default TfidfVectorizer to add a stemmer.

Here is a runnable example (this will download a 3mb training file to your disk, omit the urllib parts to run on your own sample):

```
#####################################
# Loading Data
#####################################
import urllib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk.stem  
raw = urllib.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/597/assets/trainingdata.txt").read()
file = open("to_delete.txt","w").write(raw)
###
def extract_training():
    f = open("to_delete.txt")
    N = int(f.readline())
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in xrange(N):
        line  = f.readline()
        label,text =  int(line[0]), line[2:]
        X.append(text)
        y.append(label)
    return X,y
X_train, y_train =  extract_training()    
#############################################
# Extending Tfidf to have only stemmed features
#############################################
english_stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')

class StemmedTfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):
    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc: (english_stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc))

tfidf = StemmedTfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1))
#############################################
# Line below takes 6-7 seconds on my machine
#############################################
Xv = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
```

I tried converting the list `X_train` into an np.array but there was no difference in performance.